# How do I turn off Windows 7 screen dimming before log in?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

I'm running windows 7 (on a ThinkPad), and at some point I checked an option somewhere that dims the log in screen.  The problem is that it dims it to be almost impossible to read, and I can't find the setting where I did this.  (It's remotely possible that it was in software that shipped with the ThinkPad, and is not a standard part of Windows 7, but I don't think so.)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open Lenovo Power Manager (in Advanced mode)
go to second tab "Global Power Settings"
and just below second group "Dynamic Brightness Control"
Then you would have few checkboxes to choose when to dim the display.
There are shut down/up, logoff, switch user, screen lock and screen saver.